# Handling error SOAP client

Tags: delphi, exception, soap, wsdl, fault

I need to write a SOAP client with SSL in Delphi 2007. 
I used the WSDL importer $Rev: 10138 to generate the code. I have problem with error handling.
In the code are the following classes (among other)

```
SzczegolyBledu = class(TRemotable)
private
  Fkod: KodBledu;
  Fzrodlo: KrotkiTekst;
  Fopis: KrotkiTekst;
published
  property kod:    KodBledu     read Fkod write Fkod;
  property zrodlo: KrotkiTekst  read Fzrodlo write Fzrodlo;
  property opis:   KrotkiTekst  read Fopis write Fopis;
end;

BladTechniczny = class(ERemotableException)
private
  Fkod: KodBledu;
  Fopis: KrotkiTekst;
  Fopis_Specified: boolean;
  FopisTechniczny: DlugiTekst;
  FopisTechniczny_Specified: boolean;
  procedure Setopis(Index: Integer; const AKrotkiTekst: KrotkiTekst);
  function  opis_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
  procedure SetopisTechniczny(Index: Integer; const ADlugiTekst: DlugiTekst);
  function  opisTechniczny_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
published
  property kod:            KodBledu     read Fkod write Fkod;
  property opis:           KrotkiTekst  Index (IS_OPTN) read Fopis write Setopis stored opis_Specified;
  property opisTechniczny: DlugiTekst   Index (IS_OPTN) read FopisTechniczny write SetopisTechniczny stored opisTechniczny_Specified;
end;

bladTechniczny2 = class(BladTechniczny)
private
published
end;

Array_Of_SzczegolyBledu = array of SzczegolyBledu;   { -- }

BladBiznesowy = class(ERemotableException)
private
  Fkod: KodBledu;
  Fopis: KrotkiTekst;
  Fopis_Specified: boolean;
  Fszczegoly: Array_Of_SzczegolyBledu;
  Fszczegoly_Specified: boolean;
  procedure Setopis(Index: Integer; const AKrotkiTekst: KrotkiTekst);
  function  opis_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
  procedure Setszczegoly(Index: Integer; const AArray_Of_SzczegolyBledu: Array_Of_SzczegolyBledu);
  function  szczegoly_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
public
  destructor Destroy; override;
published
  property kod:       KodBledu                 read Fkod write Fkod;
  property opis:      KrotkiTekst              Index (IS_OPTN) read Fopis write Setopis stored opis_Specified;
  property szczegoly: Array_Of_SzczegolyBledu  Index (IS_OPTN) read Fszczegoly write Setszczegoly stored szczegoly_Specified;
end;

bladBiznesowy2 = class(BladBiznesowy)
private
published
end;

implementation

destructor BladBiznesowy.Destroy;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := 0 to Length(Fszczegoly)-1 do
    FreeAndNil(Fszczegoly[I]);
  SetLength(Fszczegoly, 0);
  inherited Destroy;
end; 

procedure BladBiznesowy.Setopis(Index: Integer; const AKrotkiTekst: KrotkiTekst);
begin
  Fopis := AKrotkiTekst;
  Fopis_Specified := True;
end;

function BladBiznesowy.opis_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
begin
  Result := Fopis_Specified;
end;

procedure BladBiznesowy.Setszczegoly(Index: Integer; const AArray_Of_SzczegolyBledu: Array_Of_SzczegolyBledu);
begin
  Fszczegoly := AArray_Of_SzczegolyBledu;
  Fszczegoly_Specified := True;
end;

function BladBiznesowy.szczegoly_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
begin
  Result := Fszczegoly_Specified;
end;

procedure BladTechniczny.Setopis(Index: Integer; const AKrotkiTekst: KrotkiTekst);
begin
  Fopis := AKrotkiTekst;
  Fopis_Specified := True;
end;

function BladTechniczny.opis_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
begin
  Result := Fopis_Specified;
end;

procedure BladTechniczny.SetopisTechniczny(Index: Integer; const ADlugiTekst: DlugiTekst);
begin
  FopisTechniczny := ADlugiTekst;
  FopisTechniczny_Specified := True;
end;

function BladTechniczny.opisTechniczny_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
begin
  Result := FopisTechniczny_Specified;
end;

initialization

  RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSClass(BladTechniczny, 'http://msw.gov.pl/srp/v3_0/uslugi/wspolne/', 'BladTechniczny');
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSClass(bladTechniczny2, 'http://msw.gov.pl/srp/v3_0/uslugi/subskrypcje/', 'bladTechniczny2', 'bladTechniczny');

  RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSClass(BladBiznesowy, 'http://msw.gov.pl/srp/v3_0/uslugi/wspolne/', 'BladBiznesowy');
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSClass(bladBiznesowy2, 'http://msw.gov.pl/srp/v3_0/uslugi/subskrypcje/', 'bladBiznesowy2', 'bladBiznesowy');
```

SOAPUI generates for me response

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>
   <soap:Body>
     <soap:Fault>
         <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Błąd: xxx</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <ns2:bladTechniczny xmlns:ns2="http://msw.gov.pl/srp/v3_0/uslugi/subskrypcje/">
               <kod>xxx</kod>
               <opisx>xxx</opis>
               <opisTechniczny></opisTechniczny>
            </ns2:bladTechniczny>
         </detail>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

In Delphi is not generated RemotableException **bladTechniczny**  but i get EIdHTTPProtocolException
Is there a way to change it ?

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

If I hit the web service endpoint `http://msw.gov.pl/srp/v3_0/uslugi/subskrypcje/`, the server redirects to `https://msw.gov.pl/srp/v3_0/uslugi/subskrypcje/`.

So I suggest that you import the WSDL using the https URI, and try again.

Comment: Server generates Internal Server Error. The cause is validation of data requests. When analyzing the response in SoapUI, I see that the server sends Fault. But I get an exception EIdHTTPProtocolException and do not have access to a fault. What can I do to handle fault ?